# How to remove even indexes in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Newbie to functional program, I need to remove even indexed elements from a list, so far i can only create a list, from 1 to n.
The list : [1,2,3,4,5,6...100]
Goal: [1,3,5,7,9...99]

```
main = do
    input <- readLn :: IO Int
    let a = input 
    let list=[1..a] 
    putStrLn $ show list
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you aim to achieve. What is the input? The upperbound of the list?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Updated  the question, yes, I am trying to solve the following problem with haskell : https://www.eolymp.com/en/problems/1964

Comment: If you had an empty list, what would the expected result be? Probably `[]`. If you had a list with a single element (`[a]`) the result would just be `[a]`. If you had a list of two elements (`[a, b]`), the expected result would be `[a]`. Can you extrapolate this to achieve the same effect for an entire list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can produce a list that only contains the odd elements by making use of a range that starts with `1` then `3` and as limit `a`:

```
main = do
    input <- readLn :: IO Int
    print [1, 3..a]
```

This will make a call to [**`enumFromThenTo :: Enum a => a -> a -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:enumFromThenTo) that will thus generate a list with steps of two.

You can also make two functions with mutual recursion:

```
evens :: [a] -> [a]
evens [] = []
evens (_:xs) = odds xs

odds :: [a] -> [a]
odds [] = []
odds (x:xs) = x : evens xs
```

Then calling `odds` on a list `[1 .. 100]` produces:

```
Prelude> odds [1 .. 100]
[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63,65,67,69,71,73,75,77,79,81,83,85,87,89,91,93,95,97,99]
```

and `evens` can be used to obtain the elements on even indices.

Elaborating slightly on what this mutual recursion looks like with a simple example list:

```
odds [1, 4, 2, 7, 9, 6]
1 : evens [4, 2, 7, 9, 6]
1 : odds [4, 7, 9, 6]
1 : 2 : evens [7, 9, 6]
1 : 2 : odds [9, 6]
1 : 2 : 9 : evens [6]
1 : 2 : 9 : odds []
1 : 2 : 9 : []
[1, 2, 9]
```

or if you want to remove items that are even (not even indices), you can work with:

```
Prelude> filter odd [1, 4 .. 100]
[1,7,13,19,25,31,37,43,49,55,61,67,73,79,85,91,97]
```

Comment: The problem is not to have an array of odd numbers, but to remove the even indices, I might need to do this multiple times for example
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 1 3 5 7
 1 5

Comment: There is no test in the answer for whether a number is odd or even.

Comment: @Chris: The original answer’s example and the one you added are both misleading in that regard, since the odd indices also coincidentally contain odd values (resp. even).

Comment: Good point. Updated edit.

Comment: `oddIndices = concat . zipWith ($) (cycle [(:[]), mempty])`